# Composite key, `unique_constraint` issue

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have migration like:

```
defmodule N.Repo.Migrations.CreateAuth do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:auths, primary_key: false) do
      add :oauth_id, :string, primary_key: true
      add :provider, :string, primary_key: true

      add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing, type: :binary_id)

      timestamps()
    end

    create index(:auths, [:user_id])
  end
end
```

And model configured as follows:

```
defmodule N.Auth do
  use N.Web, :model

  @primary_key false
  schema "auths" do
    field :oauth_id, :string, primary_key: true
    field :provider, :string, primary_key: true

    belongs_to :user, N.User

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:oauth_id, :provider])
    |> validate_required([:oauth_id, :provider])
    |> unique_constraint(:oauth_id, :auths_oauth_id_index)
  end
end
```

Following the suggestion from [Phoenix guidelines](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-custom-primary-keys#section-composite-primary-keys).

In my tests:

```
defmodule N.AuthTest do
  use N.ModelCase

  import N.Factory

  alias N.Auth

  test "changeset with duplicates" do
    auth_params =
      %{provider: :facebook,
        oauth_id: "1234"}
    insert(:auth, auth_params)

    changeset = Auth.changeset(%Auth{}, auth_params)

    assert {:error, changeset} = Repo.insert(changeset)
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, when running them, I have following error:

```
  1) test N.Auth.changeset/2 changeset with duplicates (N.AuthTest)
     test/models/auth_test.exs:31
     ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Access.fetch/2
     stacktrace:
       (elixir) lib/access.ex:147: Access.fetch(:auths_oauth_id_index, :name)
       (elixir) lib/access.ex:179: Access.get/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:1629: Ecto.Changeset.unique_constraint/3
       test/models/auth_test.exs:37: (test)
```

If I understand it correctly, this is due to lack of:

```
create unique_index(:auths, [:oauth_id, :provider])
```

like described in [`unique_constraint/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#unique_constraint/3) documentation. Obviously, I don't want to create the index, as it's created automatically by setting the composite primary key.

Do you have any advice how to take that further?

**UPDATE**

The index name used here is suggested by `Ecto` itself - when I use code without specifying the index name, like so:

```
    |> unique_constraint(:oauth_id)
```

when I run the test, the error messages is as follows:

```
  1) test N.Auth.changeset/2 changeset with duplicates (N.AuthTest)
     test/models/auth_test.exs:31
     ** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert struct:

         * unique: auths_pkey

     If you would like to convert this constraint into an error, please
     call unique_constraint/3 in your changeset and define the proper
     constraint name. The changeset defined the following constraints:

         * unique: auths_oauth_id_index

     stacktrace:
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:403: anonymous fn/4 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.constraints_to_errors/3
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1183: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:393: Ecto.Repo.Schema.constraints_to_errors/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:193: anonymous fn/11 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:595: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.wrap_in_transaction/6
       (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:472: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.do_transaction/3
       (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:973: DBConnection.transaction_run/4
       (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:897: DBConnection.run_begin/3
       (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:671: DBConnection.transaction/3
       test/models/auth_test.exs:41: (test)
```

The same error occurs, when I'm trying [`check_constraint/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#check_constraint/3), like:

```
    |> check_constraint(:oauth_id, name: :auths_oauth_id_index)
```

Comment: Try `unique_constraint(:oauth_id, name: :auths_pkey)`. If that doesn't work replace `:auths_pkey` with the name of the actual index that was created. Let me know if it works and I'll post an explanation.

Comment: Hi @Dogbert, thanks for your suggestion! This is exactly what I've done so far. When I do as you suggested, error message stays almost the same: `(elixir) lib/access.ex:147: Access.fetch(:auths_pkey, :name)`. I've updated my question with a bit more information why I've gone with `auths_oauth_id_index`

Comment: Are you _absolutely_ sure `|> unique_constraint(:oauth_id, name: :auths_pkey)` doesn't work? Can you try restarting the server after adding this?

Comment: @Dogbert, I don't think restarting the server will do much here (yet, I've done that), as I'm running my tests with `mix test`; I've even tried removing the build for full recompile `rm -rf _build`, but this still doesn't solve the problem. If that helps, I'm using `:ecto 2.0.2`, `:phoenix 1.2.0` and `:phoenix_ecto 3.0.0`. My suspicion is, Ecto can't obtain meta information from `__schema__` (thus, fail of `Access.fetch(:auths_pkey, :name)`), because I haven't built my unique index explicitly (by that I mean adding `create unique_index(:auths, [:oauth_id, :provider])` in migration)

Comment: @Dogbert! I misread your first suggestion! What I was using was `unique_constraint(:oauth_id, :auths_pkey)`, instead of your code sample of `unique_constraint(:oauth_id, name: :auths_pkey)` which works! My apologies for confusion! Please, add it as an answer, so I can mark it as correct! Again - so sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that you were passing the index name directly as the 3rd argument to `unique_constraint` whereas it needed to be a keyword list item with key `:name`.

My first clue was this error message:

```
Access.fetch(:auths_oauth_id_index, :name)
```

and the fact that the 3rd argument you passed was `:auths_oauth_id_index`. That error means Ecto was trying to access the `:name` key from the value and since it was not a list or map, it was throwing an error.

Also, the index name was not `:auths_oauth_id_index` but the default one Ecto assigns to primary keys: `:auths_pkey` (the format is  `table_name <> "_pkey"`).

Final working code:

```
|> unique_constraint(:‌​oauth_id, name: :auths_pkey)
```